# Not running on AppKit (main) thread when displaying Game Center leaderboard in OS X

Tags: macos, thread-safety, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

Whenever I try to view game centers leaderboard ion OS X with this code:

```
GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController 
                             = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc]init];
gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;

if (gameCenterController !=nil) {
    GKDialogController *sdc =[GKDialogController sharedDialogController];
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    sdc.parentWindow = [NSApp mainWindow];
    [sdc presentViewController:gameCenterController];

}
```

(This is nearly a exact copy of apples documentation)

I get a:

> *** Assertion failure in void assertRunningOnAppKitThread()(), /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-99/ViewBridgeUtilities.m:535
>   An uncaught exception was raised
>   not running on AppKit (main) thread

The method is invoked by a click on a menuitem.
What I have tried was wrapping the method in a 
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()
block with no success.

Edit: Added the stack trace: 
[image]
- Seems that it starts from main thread (menu click) and Game Center itself starts a new queue.?

What did I miss? Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose you need to defer the presentViewController call (and the line before that) to the main thread. Try performSelectorOnMainThread or GCD dispatch_sync with the main queue.

Comment: I already tried the dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue() - trick by wrapping the inner part of the if-statement. Will a 'performOnMainThrad' have any differences? It seems that the game controller itself will switch the thread.